# Cannot find resource for the request $batch Sharepoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest, odata

When i try to execute sample batch code in Sharepoint server 2013 i'm getting the error '***Cannot find resource for the request $batch***'

Int16 listRetrievalCount = 0;

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // Get the host web's URL.
            sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        }

        // Create the parent request
        var batchRequest = new BatchODataRequest(String.Format("{0}/_api/", sharepointUrl)); // ctor adds "$batch"
        batchRequest.SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        using (var oDataMessageWriter = new ODataMessageWriter(batchRequest))
        {
            var oDataBatchWriter = oDataMessageWriter.CreateODataBatchWriter();
            oDataBatchWriter.WriteStartBatch();

            // Create the two child query operations.
            oDataBatchWriter.CreateOperationRequestMessage(
                 "GET", new Uri(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Composed Looks')/items?$select=Title"));
            listRetrievalCount++;

            oDataBatchWriter.CreateOperationRequestMessage(
               "GET", new Uri(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items?$select=Title"));
            listRetrievalCount++;

            oDataBatchWriter.WriteEndBatch();
            oDataBatchWriter.Flush();
        }

        // Parse the response and bind the data to the UI controls
        var oDataResponse = batchRequest.GetResponse();
```

Eorror is thrown in GetResponse function.
Code taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn903506.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this code against SharePoint Online / O365 or against an on-premise SharePoint server? AFAIK, the $batch operation is supported only in case of the former ones, see [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn903506.aspx#sectionSection0):

> **SharePoint Online and the Office 365 APIs** implement the OData $batch
>   query option

Comment: i'm tring in the on-premise SharePoint server. it will work ?

Comment: No, based on my experience and based on the official documentation I referred to, it won't.

Comment: When i excute code i'm getting the CONTENT-TYPE as 'application/atom+xml;type=feed;charset=utf-8' in response. Is there any way to get the json in response

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to fall back to 2010 batch operation. but but you won't be able to use listdata.svc if you need something not related to the Lists

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/$batch
```