# Batch update/create list items using REST API in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, batch

I know the OData batch process built into SharePoint Online 2016 and O365 has not made it to SharePoint 2013 Online, but I have read a few places that say using a batch create/update IS possible in SP2013 by using the SP2010 _vti_bin/listdata.svc to do batch updates/inserts.  In fact I have some code I use in Excel that does something similar by writing the entire range of data to SharePoint in a batch using the vti_bin/listdata.svc method, but I haven't figured out how to do this using the REST API yet as there are a lot of extra steps.

I have read postings on the SharePoint Stack Exchange from the following places that tell how to do it:

[Cannot find resource for the request $batch Sharepoint server 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140020/cannot-find-resource-for-the-request-batch-sharepoint-server-2013)

[$batch operations on SharePoint 2013 on-premise not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191178/batch-operations-on-sharepoint-2013-on-premise-not-working)

Except I cannot get it to work.  I am following the code in this example and making the changes as needed looking at the pastebin example the one person posted [here](http://pastebin.com/2EMLXq5i), but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

I am following the instructions from here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/780289/save-mutiple-records-to-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-in-a/

and from what they are saying it looks very similar to what he has in there.

Here is the code I am using:

```
this.batchUpdate = function (model, list, errorMsg) {
            var batchContents = new Array();
            var changeSetId = self.generateUUID();
            var batchUuid = self.generateUUID();
            var endpointUrl = SPUrl + '_vti_bin/listdata.svc/' + list

            //create the changeSet
            for (var index = 0; index < model.length; index++) {

                batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
                batchContents.push('Content-Type:application/http');
                batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                batchContents.push('');
                batchContents.push('POST ' + endpointUrl + ' HTTP/1.1');
                batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
                batchContents.push('Accept: application/json');
                batchContents.push('');
                batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(model[index]));
                batchContents.push('');
            }
            //End changeset to create Data
            batchContents.push('--changeSetId_' + changeSetId + '--');

            //generate batch body
            var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

            endpointUrl = SPUrl + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/$batch';

            //create batch specific header
            var batchRequestHeader = {
                'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_' + batchUuid + '"'
            };

            return $.ajax({
                url: endpointUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                headers: batchRequestHeader,
                data: batchBody
            }).then(function (data, request) {
                return data.d;
            }, function (error) {
                errorMsg !== undefined && errorMsg !== null ? alertify.error(errorMsg + error.status) : null
            });
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I really need to get this functionality working ASAP!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you check the `batchBody` and `batchRequestHeader` after setting the value, does it look correct?

Answer (score 0):

"SharePoint Online (and on-premises SharePoint 2016 and later) and the Office 365 APIs implement the OData $batch query option "
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis 
I don't think you can make it work in SP2013...

Comment: Someone says they were able to get it working in SP 2013...it doesn't matter at this point I just created a loop through the items that needed to be updated and it works fine.